# Django formset with crispy - submit buttons not submitting

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm using a FormSet with crispy, and have but a submit button on each row, however hitting submit does not update records currently. 
I've searched and found some similar answers which suggest the submit isn't inside the form, but mine are. Also that a form action is missing, but none of my other crispy forms have actions and they work without issue.

Are there any other reasons seen from the code below that would cause the records to not save?

forms.py

```
class ChangeGroupForm(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChangeGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.css_class = 'form-inline'
        self.form_id = 'changegroup_form'
        self.form_show_labels = False 
        self.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(                          
                    Div(
                        Field('group', placeholder='Group', css_class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"),
                    css_class='col-lg-3'
                    ),    
                    Div(
                        Field('gps', placeholder='gps coords', css_class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"),
                    css_class='col-lg-8'
                    ), 
                    Div(
                        HTML("""<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary mt-1"/>"""),
                    css_class='col-lg-1'
                    ),               
                css_class='row'
                ),
            )
        )
        self.render_required_fields = True
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def db_change_groups(request):
    change_form = modelformset_factory(ChangeGroup, fields=('group','gps'))
    change_form_helper = ChangeGroupForm()

    return render(request, 'home/db_change_groups.html', {
        "change_form": change_form,
        "change_form_helper": change_form_helper,
        })
```

template.html

```
{% crispy change_form change_form_helper %}
```

rendered html

```
<form id="changegroup_form" method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
        value="7v0000CPl3G70M6HLfF2FAiwefdfsdgdfwewdf7Gp4nay1hFqZ1Y34SBUA000mHBZQ54">
    <div> <input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="10" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS"> <input type="hidden"
            name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="9" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS"> <input type="hidden"
            name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS"> <input type="hidden"
            name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS"> </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div id="div_id_form-0-group" class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls "> <input type="text" name="form-0-group" value="A" maxlength="50"
                            class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 textinput textInput form-control" placeholder="Group"
                            id="id_form-0-group"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div id="div_id_form-0-gps" class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls "> <input type="text" name="form-0-gps" maxlength="255"
                            class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 textinput textInput form-control" placeholder="gps coords"
                            id="id_form-0-gps"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" />
            </div>

        </div>

    </div> <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="1" id="id_form-0-id">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div id="div_id_form-1-group" class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls "> <input type="text" name="form-1-group" value="B" maxlength="50"
                            class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 textinput textInput form-control" placeholder="Group"
                            id="id_form-1-group"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div id="div_id_form-1-gps" class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls "> <input type="text" name="form-1-gps" maxlength="255"
                            class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 textinput textInput form-control" placeholder="gps coords"
                            id="id_form-1-gps"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" />
            </div>

        </div>

    </div> 

    </div> <input type="hidden" name="form-9-id" id="id_form-9-id">
</form>
```

Comment: What's the error? What do you see in the django dev server? Or is there an issue in the browser console? Your view doesn't validate or save the form during a POST.

Comment: I dont see anything, the page just refreshes and the field hasn't saved. I assumed using a model_factoryset would create these views for me? I need to do them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach somthing like this to your view

```
def db_change_groups(request):
    ....
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChangeGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Access cleaned data with
            group = form.cleaned_data['group']
            # Then you can save this to a model.

            # return success template or something
        else:
            # Check for errors.
```

If you created the form with ModelForm instead of FormHelper you could use form.save() which you automatically save it to the model.